# How to bind set of enum values to form:select multiple="true" in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, enums, spring-form

I have form-backing object:

```
public class MyDto {
  private Set<MyEnum> myEnum = new HashSet<MyEnum>();
  // getters/setters

  public MyEnym[] getMyEnumValues() {
     return MyEnum.values();
  }
}
public MyEnum {
A, B, C
}
```

What is the way to show all enum values in `<form:select multiple="true"/>`  and achieve automatically mapping of selected values to `myEnum` field in my form-backing object?

**Update:**
Some code:

```
<form:select path="myEnum" multiple="true" items="${myDto.myEnumValues}"/>
```

When submitting form, selected values in multiselect are presented in HTTP request:

```
myEnum: A
myEnum: B


public String saveMyDto(@Valid @ModelAttribute("myDto") MyDto myDto) {

    log.debug("Enum list: " + myDto.myEnum().toString());
    .... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The key idea is to assign the values to the `item` attribute of  `form:select`.

I the controller that populate the view with the form add

```
  modelMap.addAttribute("possibleValues", MyEnum.values);
```

in the jsp use:

```
<form:select multiple="true" items="${possibleValues}" path="myDto.myEnum"/>
```

---

*(On the other hand, I remember that I have had a look at the select tag implementation of spring, and found that it the value of the actual value is an Enum, then spring automatically use all `Enum.values` as default value for `items` (but I am not 100% sure) )*

The Controller method should look like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/form", Method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView whatever() {
     ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
     modelMap.addAttribute("possibleValues", MyEnum.values);
     return new ModelMap("nameOfTheView", modelMap);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/whatever", Method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView whatever(MyDto myDto) {
      Sysout.println(myDto);
}
```

Comment: thanks. I tried it, but it doesn't work: it sends choosed values from multi-select, but field `myEnum` in form-backing object is empty..

Comment: Please post the code of you controller method, and the exact request (parameter and value) that sended to the server on form submit

Comment: Updated. Please note, all other parameters from HTML FORM are mappred to form-backing object fields fine

Comment: @MyTitle: you need to condigure the jsp, so that the selected value is submited with the key `myDto.myEnum`

Comment: After setting `path` to `myDto.myEnum` i get runtime exception. I think it's not allowed, because I already have reference to `myDto` in <form:form modelAttribute="myDto" ... >

Comment: Please post the complete controller, jsp and command (remove the not relevant parts, but do not modify the methods... that are invoked). I believe the problem is somewhere in there, maybe a misspelled variable name or something like that.